# Zombie cookies are apparently stored in different locations, inside a computer, common to all Web Browsers installed on that specific computer, right?

Tags: browser, ip, cookies, portable

Zombie cookies are apparently stored in different locations, inside a computer, common to all Web Browsers installed on that specific computer, right?

Does the same process works when someone is using Portable Web Browsers installed inside USB sticks plugged into the user's computer? Which means, the Portable Browsers can be also identified (as the Installed Web Browsers can be by using zombie cookies) as coming from the same source computer using those zombie cookies?

Related Link: [If you visit a website they will know your IP address. But what about when you change broadband connection?](https://superuser.com/questions/762330/if-you-visit-a-website-they-will-know-your-ip-address-but-what-about-when-you-c)

Comment: Sorry, but your question isn't very clear

Comment: Someone here named "Steve Jessop", has a lot of thoughts about these, I guess. I just don't know how to direct these kind of questionings to him!

Comment: You better had added a link to your previous question: http://superuser.com/questions/762330/if-you-visit-a-website-they-will-know-your-ip-address-but-what-about-when-you-c

Comment: I'm not sure how, though.